# Difficulties deploying Flask app to Heroku for the first time

Tags: heroku

I'm deploying the first flask app in heroku and i'm getting some errors that i can't figure it out. Procfile is --> **web: gunicorn app:app**
requirements.txt:

The error i get is:

````
``` 'sklearn.ensemble.forest'**
``` 2021-04-26T23:38:52.683083+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-26 23:38:52 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker 
``` exiting (pid: 7)
``` 2021-04-26T23:38:52.851532+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-26 23:38:52 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker 
``` with pid 7 was terminated due to signal 15
``` 2021-04-26T23:38:52.938143+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-26 23:38:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting 
``` down: Master
``` 2021-04-26T23:38:52.938211+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-04-26 23:38:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: 
``` *Worker failed to boot.*
``` 2021-04-26T23:38:53.048829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: **Process exited with status 3**
``` 2021-04-26T23:38:53.136363+00:00 heroku[web.1]: **State changed from up to crashed**
``` 2021-04-26T23:38:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: **Build succeeded**
``` 2021-04-26T23:39:03.908807+00:00 heroku[router]: **at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"**
```method=GET  
``` path="/" 
``` 2021-04-26T23:39:04.254733+00:00 heroku[router]: **at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"** method=GET
``` path="/favicon.ico" 


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH7ga.jpg
````

Comment: Seems scikit-learn is not quite supported without using something like Docker: https://help.heroku.com/S48C2M3H/can-i-use-scientific-python-libraries-scipy-scikit-learn-etc-on-heroku

Comment: Is my first project so im really confus.What you suggest me to do?

Comment: In my opinion Docker isn't that easy to just pick up in a short amount of time, but if you familiarize yourself with the basic ideas then you should try following the structure of this repository: https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-miniconda

Comment: I don't know if this is related but when i run the app.py from command line works fine but when i activate the virtual environment i still got the same error.

Comment: You mean the command line on your local machine, right? It should work fine on your local machine, the issue is just with the dependencies being supported by Heroku.

Comment: Yes my local machine. I understand that but when i do: env\Scripts\activate and try to do it again app.py i have the same error that i get from heroku logs